# How to translate two languages at the same time without delay for instance: "two online games written in different languages"

Tags: connection, streaming

I have a question about writing a script which can manage to play online games in different codes. I think the easiest to understand is when I say I need to make a platform on which Playstation as xbox players are allowed to play online Modern Warfare 3 together.

Mathematically it seems it is possible: at the end you have two different screens which project the same. On the platform, Sony and Microsoft players stream their code or screen to the platform and play together. Big problem is that you get it delivered in 2 different codes which you have to translate to one language in less than 0,001 second.

Honestly said I have to get into this stuff but I cannot get much further.

Do you have any tips, other forums or solutions for this problem? Maybe it is writing a new language? (Google is technically using it for Google-translating over the phone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the game this might not be possible even in theory. Many console games use a peer-to-peer lock-step synchronization model for multiplayer. Games that use this approach only send each other the player input from the other consoles and rely on deterministic simulation (the same inputs produce the same outputs) to keep the systems synchronized.

This only works when the exact same compiled code is running on the same CPU for all players. Games with this networking model usually have periodic desynch checks to make sure that the different systems haven't drifted out of sync with each other. A desynch failure is usually considered a fatal error and either a bug in the game or evidence of attempted cheating by one of the players.

Other multiplayer games use a client server model and so it would be possible in theory to allow different consoles to play against each other. Reverse engineering the network protocol would be a formidable technical challenge however and it would be a difficult problem to get this to work reliably.

Even if you could solve the technical problems though you would likely have even bigger legal issues to overcome. Sony and Microsoft don't want to allow cross platform play so even though it would be possible in theory to make this work with a client server multiplayer game developers aren't able to implement it. A third party trying to make this work would likely have to deal with legal challenges from Microsoft, Sony and the game developer.